# Need help optimizing this array builder

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, optimization

My current code has two major bottlenecks, one I can improve for sure, but this one has me stuck. It eats up roughly 50% of my run time, and only gets worse.

What should it do?
It should take an array (a walk) from Walks and break it into two new arrays, A and B. The rules look a bit odd, but I'm sure they're straightforward enough.
Each walk should have even-N non-negative integers, and a pair is simply a list of 2 lists of integers, each list also being length N.
L is N/2.

```py
#example pair: [[1,2,5,6,-4,-1],[8,12,-3,7,4,9]]
#example walks:[[1,0,2,5,3,1]] just 1 walk in this example. Could be k many.
#L = 3
newpairs=[]
for walk in walks:
    Anew = [0 for j in range(2*L)]
    Bnew = [0 for j in range(2*L)]
    for r in range(L):
        Anew[r]   = int((pair[0][r]+walk[r])/2)
        Anew[r+L] = int((pair[0][r]-walk[r])/2)
        Bnew[r]   = int((pair[1][r]+walk[r+L])/2)
        Bnew[r+L] = int((pair[1][r]-walk[r+L])/2)
    newpair = [Anew,Bnew]
    newpairs.append(newpair)

#output:[[[1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1], [6, 7, -1, 1, 4, -2]]]
```

I realize this may be a shot in the dark, but I'm happy to answer any questions to further clarify aspects of the code. My project cannot go much further without optimizing this piece. Its blowing up run times by over 50% and will only get worse as I push bigger sets through.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm seems simple enough and doesn't have any glaring performance mistakes. You probably won't be reducing the run time by an order of magnitude or anything like it. There are some smaller optimizations you can do, though.

1) Use `list` multiplication notation for initializing your `Anew` and `Bnew` `list`s. Replace this:

```
Anew = [0 for j in range(2*L)]
Bnew = [0 for j in range(2*L)]
```

with this:

```
Anew = [0]*2*L
Bnew = [0]*2*L
```

Benchmarking:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('[0 for x in range(300)]')
7.822149500000023
>>> timeit.timeit('[0]*300')
0.8999562000000196
```

2) Use floor division. Replace

```
Anew[r]   = int((pair[0][r]+walk[r])/2)
```

and similar lines, with this:

```
Anew[r] = (pair[0][r]+walk[r])//2
```

Benchmark:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('[int((x+y)/2) for x in range(-5,5) for y in range(-5,5)]')
23.69675469999993
>>> timeit.timeit('[(x+y)//2 for x in range(-5,5) for y in range(-5,5)]')
11.680407500000001
```

Beyond that, you might want to look into using `numpy` as it's almost always faster than the standard library for working with lists/arrays.